# sSMTP no longer works - 'Invalid response: 501 5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com invalid, closing connection.'

Tags: php, linux, email, ssmtp

As the title/tags say, I run sSMTP on Linux for a PHP server.

Whenever I try to send an email, I get these errors (that do not show up in PHP, only in the logs/ 'sudo service sendmail status' or 'sudo service php5-fpm status')

From /var/log/mail.log

```
Mar 31 03:34:34 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[2004]: Creating SSL connection to host
Mar 31 03:34:34 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[2004]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4 HELO/ELO argument MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com invalid, closing connection. v74sm9147441pfa.7- gsmtp (MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com)
Mar 31 03:34:34 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[2004]: SSL connection using (null)
Mar 31 03:34:34 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[2004]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

From /var/log/mail.err and mail.warn

```
Mar 31 03:34:10 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[1997]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
Mar 31 03:34:34 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[2004]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com invalid, closing connection. v74sm9147441pfa.7 - gsmtp (MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com)
Mar 31 03:34:34 ip-172-31-22-38 sSMTP[2004]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

My /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com

AuthUser=MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com
AuthPass=[removed]
UseSTARTTLS=YES
# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

My revaliases

```
root:MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
localusername:MYEMAILADDRESS@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Answer (score 21):

my **ssmtp.conf** included `hostname=xxx@gmail.com`, I changed it to `hostname=localhost` and the problem was solved.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well in Java. I had to use props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "localhost");

Answer (score 7):

After pulling my hair out for ages, I finally strapped down and copied the config from Arch Linux's wiki article for Gmail and SSMTP, and that ended up working! Be sure to triple check your configs, folks!

```
# The user that gets all the mails (UID < 1000, usually the admin)
root=username@gmail.com

# The mail server (where the mail is sent to), both port 465 or 587 should be acceptable
# See also http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78799
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# The address where the mail appears to come from for user authentication.
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=localhost

# Use SSL/TLS before starting negotiation
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes

# Username/Password
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=password

# Email 'From header's can override the default domain?
FromLineOverride=yes
```